# dispatcherTimer doesn't work accurately

Tags: c#

I need to capture 10 frames per second of a live camera for 15 min. I used dispatcherTimer class but seems  it doesn't work accurately. How to make it accurate? I even don't save the image because it is time consuming and i just keep it in the memory but still it doesn't work correctly.
should I use another library?

```
counter01 = new DispatcherTimer();
counter01.Tick += new EventHandler(counter01_Tick);
counter01.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0,100); // every 100 milliseconds == 10 frames per seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) that:

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, 
>   but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs.

You can check [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is as accurate as it *can* be.  Which requires your UI thread to be responsive, quickly dispatching any messages it gets.  Including the "time is up" notifications that DispatcherTimer generates, the ones that generate the Tick event.

The usual hangup with seeing DispatcherTimer triggering the Tick event handler late is that you have a firehose problem.  In other words, the amount of time required by the event handler is *longer* than the timer's Interval property value.  This takes care of itself in the manner you expect, whenever you try to do more than the machine can handle then whatever you are trying to do just runs later.

No lack of firehose problems with video, one frame can contain a lot of data.  A typical hidef video stream runs at 25 frames per second with each frame containing 1920x1080 pixels.  That's 25 x 1920 x 1080 x 3 = 148 megabytes/second.  Short from decompressing overhead, you can't even write the data to a disk at that rate.  Most consumer-level disk drives top out at 30 megabytes/second, give or take a factor of 2.  Lowering the frame rate to 10/sec is not enough to solve it, that's still 60 MB/sec, you have to take more drastic measures like reducing the frame size.  Or use a good video encoder that can compress video real-time.

This is a systemic problem, not a DispatcherTimer problem.  Use a profiler to get more insight, it helps you identify the true bottle-neck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your full answer @Hans , Actually  my frame size is fixed (640*480) and it is gray image which has to be saved in a binary file so each frame is 307200 KB. the number of frames cannot reduce because it has to make model of respiratory motion of patient during radiotherapy treatments and deducting each frame lose many vital information. what should i do now? what do you mean that i should use a good video recorder? is it possible to use thread programming to solve this issue? using better CPU and Ram is a good idea? but it wont guarantee again

Comment: Well, that's a much easier problem to solve.  But don't do anything until you *know* where the bottle-neck is located.  You must run a profiler so you know.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can get the `DispatcherTimer` to execute the `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event every 100 milliseconds on a good PC, but you have to address 2 problems first (see below). However, as others wrote here correctly, the processing of a frame will take some time too and the fastest reliable tick frequency might only be 5 ticks per second, if the frame processing itself takes about 100 milliseconds.

**1) Choose higher `DispatcherTimer.Priority`**

The `DispatcherTimer` runs on the WPF GUI thread. The advantage of this is that the code of `DispatcherTimer.Tick` can access any WPF control. The WPF GUI thread is controlled by a `Dispatcher`, which has a priority queue for activities the WPF GUI thread wants to execute. Rendering related activities have a higher priority than the `DispatcherTimer` has per default. The default priority of the `DispatcherTimer` is `DispatcherPriority.Background`. With this priority, the Tick can execute on my PC not faster than every 100..300 milliseconds. However, create the timer like this: `new DispatcherTimer (DispatcherPriority.Input)` and it will fire about 100..200 milliseconds. Rendering will still have a higher priority, so the user does not get a frozen GUI.

**2) Improve Tick regularity**

One problem with the `DispatcherTimer` is that if the Tick event gets delayed by x milliseconds because the WPF GUI thread is busy with other activities, the next Tick will still wait for 100+ milliseconds. However, if you shorten `DispatcherTimer.Interval` by x milliseconds, you will get a more regular firing of the tick event.

For more details see my article on CodeProject: [Improving the WPF DispatcherTimer Precision](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5323994/Improving-the-WPF-DispatcherTimer-Precision)

**Final Consideration**

Why do you want to process the frames on the WPF GUI thread ? Use a `DispatcherTimer` only if the Tick event has little to do and needs access to the WPF controls. However, if you need to execute quite some code every 100 milliseconds, better use an additional thread. Your CPU has different cores and it is a good idea to distribute the workload over 2 cores.